# Vue ElementUI MessageBox with HTML Message?

Tags: vue.js, html-parsing

I'm trying to use the MessageBox of ElementUI in my Vue app to show dynamic HTML content.  The content is coming from JSON data as an HTML string, that essentially needs to be parsed into HTML.  Normally, you could do this using the directive `v-html`, but there's no such apparent option with the MessageBox component.

Apparently, you can render HTML in the message, but you have to use the VNode method(?).  The examples I've seen show how to do this ***if*** you write the HTML in the script, but as I'm pulling preformatted HTML as a string from JSON data I don't see how I can use this to my advantage.

I might just have to switch to another modal component, but as I'm using several of the ElementUI components already I'd rather keep it all part of the same system.

Here's my script:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <el-button
            v-if="body"
            type="text"
            @click="openModal"
        >More Info
        </el-button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {

    methods: {
        openModal() {
            const h = this.$createElement;

            this.$msgbox( {
                title: this.title,
                message: this.body,
                confirmButtonText: 'OK',
                closeOnClickModal: true,
                showCancelButton: false
            } );
        }
    },
    props: {
        body: String, // The MessageBox message
        title: String // The MessageBox title
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "it has to be parsed into HTML". Are you receiving an HTML fragment from the server that you want to display in the message box, or are you receiving data from which you need to build HTML?

Comment: I'm receiving a string that is formatted with HTML (e.g. `<p>Lorem ipsum dolor <em>sit amet</em>, consectetur adipisicing elit. <a href="http://www.google.com">Eligendi, quia</a>.</p>`).  If I pass this to the  MessageBox component in the options it just displays as raw text, not formatted HTML.  Does that help to clarify?

Comment: Yes. Will it ever have Vue in it or is it just vanilla HTML?

Comment: No, it will be static (vanilla) HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One potential solution is to compile the HTML into a render function and pass that to Vue's `createElement`.

```
message: this.$createElement(Vue.compile(this.body))
```

Here is [an example](https://jsfiddle.net/mk75umyf/) based of the documentation.

Comment: Great stuff!  I had to add this to my Webpack config, but it worked!  Thanks!
`resolve: { alias: { 'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue' } }`